# Is there an easy way to move nodes into a language section?

Tags: 7, nodes, i18n-l10n

I have a site in English, with few nodes in Arabic, Aramaic, and Hebrew.

Is there a way to move each group of nodes into a language section, from the user interface?

All the nodes are created in the same site and they could share their content type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this only using the [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module

Use as replace pattern in admin/config/search/path/patterns:

```
[node:language]/[node:title]
```

[image]

Then go to admin/config/search/path/delete_bulk and delete all the aliases

[image]

And go to generate the new aliases at admin/config/search/path/update_bulk

[image]

Comment: learning English while teaching Drupal ... "ja, ja" (oeps, that's a Flemish expression, not allowed around here I guess) ... Anyway: merci (oeps, that's not English either, right?). Oh well ...

Comment: Hi Adrian, right now, most of my nodes (from whatever language) are marked as "Language neutral". You might know a way to change bulk-change a group of nodes from language neutral to the language they should be in so I could try what you suggested? The only way I know is to change each one manually in the program or SQL.

Comment: @benos I can suggest two ways. 1-. Install Views Bulk Operations (VBO) 2-. Make the change directly in the DB with SQL. There is a 3, but change one by one is very hard.

Answer (score 4):

From your comments I understand that you want to display URLs based on languages.You can achieve that by simply  editing each node and edit URL alias (under URL path settings) for each node.

If you have bunch of nodes and want to change the all URL aliases at once, follow the steps

1) Install and Enable [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) and [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) modules.

2) Define Path alias patterns in URL alias settings (admin/config/search/path/patterns)

3) Create a view with Views Bulk Operation field and select "Update node alias" option.

From the View output you can generate Auto paths for selected nodes in one click action.

Comment: @benos : I think you should also integrate your prior 2 comments in your actual question. Just a suggestion ... to make the question more easy to understand, ok?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to install rules and views bulk operation.
Make a component in order to change language of your selected nodes. (you must configure your component)

And then make a view with vbo checkbox and run your component for all selected node in a views result.